# Javascript json string split into symbols

Tags: javascript, json

I receive a standard json from my Symfony ajax controller:

```
{"id":1,"filial":0} //like this
```

and then I try to convert it to object with teh following code:

```
var filterData = new FilterData(json);//my received json here
console.log(filterData);
```

but my console.log shows me the following:

```
FilterData {0: "{", 1: """, 2: "i", 3: "d", 4: """, 5: ":", 6: "1", 7: ",", 8: """, 9: "f", 10: "i", 11: "l", 12: "i", 13: "a", 14: "l", 15: """, 16: ":", 17: "0", 18: ",", 19: """, //etc...
```

but I need a regular FilterData object. Its code is the following:

```
function FilterData(json) {
    this.id;      
    this.filial; 

for (var prop in json) this[prop] = json[prop];
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Could you try `var filterData = new FilterData(JSON.parse(json))`? I'm guessing the json variable is typed as a string.

Comment: JSON.parse(json) solved the issue, Thank you

Comment: I'll add an answer in a minute, so you can set this question to solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is that the JSON you got from the server wasn't parsed to JSON right away, but was recognised as a string. Looping through a string returns the single characters, which is very useful if you want to split a string into its characters, but not now.

The solution is to parse the string to a JSON Object:

```
var filterData = new FilterData(JSON.parse(json));
```

Another solution would be to change the headers send by the API. In this case it's a PHP application, so the following code would suffice:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```